# How to merge user identities between IdPs in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am wanting to store User Identities for the various users of a set of Service Providers using a set of IdPs (Facebook, google etc) and want to merge these users together as they use various forms of Identity and link them together (merge them) via their email address. Creating a single user with multiple authorized identities.

is this possible in wso2 Identity server? i cannot seem to find anyone who wants anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can associate user accounts using wso2 Identity Server [1]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Associating+User+Accounts

Comment: is there anyway to do this via API?

Comment: Yes. You can do this via API using UserAccountAssociationService.

Thanks
Isura